# TFS build and manifest file : the value of attribute version is invalid

Tags: wpf, tfs, manifest, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2012 build that (successfully) generates a WPF client application with a manifest file that looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="MyApp.exe" version="1.0.70109.2" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="fr" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
  <!-- ... -->
</asmv1:assembly>
```

When I try to launch the application, I have this error :

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect...

In the event log, the error is :

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Dev\MyApp.exe.Manifest".
>   Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Dev\MyApp.exe.Manifest" on line
>   3. The value "1.0.70109.2" of attribute "version" in element "assemblyIdentity" is invalid.

What I can tell so far :

- It appears that each part of version number is limited to 0-65535 inclusive : [Application Manifests on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191). Ok, good to know.
- I can change the version value by setting 1.0.1.2 and it "fix" the problem (no more errors, the application launches).
- When I build it form Visual Studio (Debug and Release), the version value is always 1.1.0.0.
- I also noticed that the version was around 60000 until recently where it jumped to around 70000. Can it possibly be dued to the year change : 2016 -> 2017?!

**My questions are :**

- **how the TFS build is generating this number?**
- **how can I change it?**

*FWIW, I also recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2015.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having upgraded from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2015, your first step should be to install Visual Studio 2015 on the build server (or else *Microsoft Build Tools 2015*). Until then, your work will be needlessly hampered by the different logic that currently underlies your local builds versus those performed on your server by the `MSBuild` TFS workflow activity. Then examine what versioning logic your build definition's selected build process template may be performing outside of MSBuild, and finally choose and implement an approach for versioning that fits your needs.

Comment: Not sure I can install anything on the build server... I'll see what I can do, thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem. You can still try this "examine what versioning logic your build definition's selected build process template may be performing outside of MSBuild".

Comment: It was indeed in the build template : the so-called version number was in fact a subset of the build date : yMMdd...
So yes, the build suddendly jumped to over 70000 since 2017...